# Enum fluent validation to accept only string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

Below is my Enum

```
public enum IdentifierType
{
    Customer = 1,
    Manager = 2,
    Director = 3
}
```

Using fluent validation in .Net core, is it possible to do validation where passing 1/"1" or 2/"2" or 3/"3" in the request should return validation error?

Passing "Customer" or "Manager" etc should work fine.

I know in C# enum type is 'int' but any thoughts if this is doable in first place?

Setup in startup.cs: Validator is registered before my converter.

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddFluentValidation(configuration =>
        {
          configuration.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();
        })
          .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(opt => { opt.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true; })
          .AddJsonOptions(serializerOption =>
          {
            serializerOption.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
            serializerOption.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
            serializerOption.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
          });
```

Attached behaviour of API using postman

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you want to explicitly disallow 1, 2, 3 or allow both int and string to be passed in?

Comment: @DavidG everything expect "Customer" or "Manager" has to return error

Comment: Second question(s)... Are you wanting this validation to happen when a request is posted to your API? And does it need to be FluentValidation that handles it? Those two things are kinda separate.

Comment: @DavidG updated question with more information. Please see if that answers yours questions. The framework is converting the enum before reaching my validator.

Comment: @DavidG to your 2nd question, yes it would be better if FluentValidation handles this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVC framework has to convert JSON to a class for FluentValidation to work.

However, you can configure MVC to validate it first.

To allow the built-in JSON serialiser in any ASP.NET MVC Core app to allow strings to be converted into an enum, you need to add the [`JsonStringEnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=net-6.0) converter in your app startup. This converter also has a parameter you can set to false to disallow integer values. For example:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
    {
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(
            new JsonStringEnumConverter(allowIntegerValues: false));
    })
```

Since it seems that '' won't prevent an int being passed in as a string, you can write your own converter. For example, something like this would work:

```
public class IdentifierTypeConverter : JsonConverter<IdentifierType>{
    public override IdentifierType Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, 
        Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var value = reader.GetString();
        
        if(value == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No null values thanks!");  
        }
        
        if(int.TryParse(value, out var _))
        {
            throw new Exception("No numbers thanks!");
        }
        
        return (IdentifierType)Enum.Parse(typeof(IdentifierType), value);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IdentifierType value, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

You could make a generic version using a JsonConverterFactory. First make the converter generic:

```
public class EnumConverter<TEnum> : JsonConverter<TEnum> where TEnum : Enum
{
 public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeToConvert.IsEnum;

    public override TEnum Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, 
        Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var value = reader.GetString();

        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No null values thanks!");
        }

        if (int.TryParse(value, out var _))
        {
            throw new Exception("No numbers thanks!");
        }

        return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), value);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TEnum value, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

And make your factory:

```
public class EnumConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeToConvert.IsEnum;

    public override JsonConverter? CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        
        JsonConverter converter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(EnumConverter<>).MakeGenericType(typeToConvert))!;

        return converter;
    }
}
```

And now add the factory instead:

```
opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new EnumConverterFactory());
```

Comment: I have already tried adding allowIntegerValues: false to my converter but that is only restricting when "IdentifierType": 2 is passed. It is not working for "IdentifierType": "2" which I can understand is being treated as a string. I need  passing "IdentifierType": "2" also return validation error.

Comment: Ah, in that case you can write your own converter.

Comment: Is it possible to make the converter generic to work any Enum type instead of just IdentifierType?

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: your EnumConverter is still using the enum IdentifierType in line return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(IdentifierType), value);

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo that I left in the reference to IdentifierType. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no direct solution in fluent validations to solve your problem. However, I would handle this scenario something as stated below:

In the below code, I have created two properties - The `IdentifierType` field is public and it will accept a string value from your client. The other field is an `enum` and it can be used internally inside your project.

```
public class YourRequestModel
{
   internal IdentifierType IdType
   {
     get
     {
        return Enum.Parse<IdentifierType>(IdentifierType);
     }
    }
   public string IdentifierType { get; }
}
```

While doing fluent validation, validate the input only against the string value.

```
public class YourRequestModelValidator: AbstractValidator<YourRequestModel> 
{
  RuleFor(x => x.IdentifierType)
            .IsEnumName(typeof(IdentifierType), caseSensitive: false);
}
```

Comment: No, IdentifierType has to be an enum. I cannot change the contract and validate it on string.

Comment: But, you are accepting only the string value from the enduser?